# How would an observer feel the Einstein Thirring Lense Effect?

Tags: general-relativity, gravity, rotational-dynamics

The Einstein Thirring Lense Effect, also known as Frame Dragging, is what happens when cellestial bodies have rotation. It states that when a body of mass is rotating around an axis it drags space and time slightly. In 2004 Nasa was able to confirm that there was some Frame Dragging caused by the earth's spin. http://www.nasa.gov/vision/earth/lookingatearth/earth_drag.html

Now here's what my question is. Let's say you had a little unbreakable sphere of matter with a radius of 50 meters suspended in a vacuum of space. Now the ball's mass alone is so little it won't have any noticible gravitational pull. Let's say you get this ball spinning so fast that any point on middle circumference (Equator), is spinning at 99% the speed of light. Would the Thirring Lense Effect become noticeable? If the Thirring Lense Effect does become noticeable, how would it feel and look? What would happen?  Would the ball take on it's own gravity?

Basically what I'm asking is what happens when frame dragging is massively scaled up to the point were you notice it.

Comment: What are you looking for that isn't already explained in e.g. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lense%E2%80%93Thirring_precession? Is there something specific you want to see calculated?

Comment: Fast compared to what? The angular velocity of the source? Also you have to be careful in what you mean by 'spinning'. The Lense-Thirring precession is a spin relative to local gyroscopes so keep that in mind. Relative to the asymptotic center of mass frame of the sphere you are not spinning.